# Graphic Jumps Up in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{title}
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=7cm]{1.pdf}\hfill\hfill

    \vspace{2cm}

     \hfill\includegraphics[width=7cm]{2.pdf}\hfill\hfill
\end{frame}
```

This creates two slides: `1.pdf` is shown on both, while `2.pdf` is only shown on the second one. The problem is that when you move from the first slide to the second, `1.pdf` jumps a little up, as if it is making room for `2.pdf` (although there are plenty of room left for it!)

Here's a demonstration:

[image]

You can get the source + PDF from [here](http://ifile.it/qjfo6hy), and see it for yourself. (It is best to view the PDF in the full-screen mode.)

I tried absolute positioning of `1.pdf`, using `textpos` (and a bunch of other techniques). However, this seems to be an overkill, and, moreover, placing the graphic at the center of the page (horizontally) seems hard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't use `<pre>` HTML tags for (La)TeX code, because it doesn't produce syntax highlighting. Indent the code by 4 spaces instead or use the '101010' button which does it for you. Please upload images using the official image provider imgur.com (using the image button) and include a your code as a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) into the question and not over an external website. Posts on TeX.SX should be selfcontained.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you very much. I didn't know that, but I'll promise to do it right next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\visible<2>{...}` macro to make the second image reserve space on the first slide to achieve correct alignment, but only be visible on the second slide. For text you can also use `\uncover<2>{...}` to achieve a semi-transparent effect (if configured), but it doesn't seem to have an effect on included images.

```
\documentclass[serif,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{default}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.3]{1.png}

      \vspace{2cm}

      \visible<2>{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{2.png}}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see it. However, if you want to center the images use the environment `center`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{overprint}
  \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[height=2cm]{1}

      \vspace{2cm}
      \onslide<2>{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{2}}
     \end{center}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I must've miscommunicated myself, and I'm sorry for that. I changed the answer to include a screenshot, as well as a link to the TeX and PDF files. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @Sadeq: see edited answer

Comment: +1. Thank you. Both your answer and Martin's are exactly what I needed, and I had to flip a coin to accept one :(